# How to sync changes from some sub-folders of a Git repo to another Git repo preserving the commit history

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have two repos repo-A and repo-B with below folder structure

```
Repo-A
—— folder1
—— folder2
—— folder3

Repo-B
—— folder1 //same copy of the repo-A folder1
—— folder2 //same copy of the repo-A folder2
```

The plan is, I'm modularising the existing repo repo-A by extracting out one business flow to a new repo repo-B. Developers still using repo-A until repo-B becomes stable. Means, developers are still pushing changes to repo-A folder1 and folder2. I need to sync the changes on these folders to repo-B folders.

I read about filter-branch and post-receive hook. But I couldn’t find a proper way to implement this. It’d be helpful if someone can point-out an optimal approach.

Comment: There is no single optimal approach. There are many approaches, each with its own pluses and minuses.

Comment: Can you mention some approach? For me, no need to automatically sync it. manual steps are fine.

Comment: The first and most important question is: are the repositories actually related? (Do the commit hash IDs match, in the two repositories?) And: since Git is based on *commits* (not files), how do you intend to treat these files? Are the repo-B files *exact copies* of the repo-A files, or do you need to find *changes* and apply them? What are the relative pathnames? Answers to these questions will determine possible paths.

Comment: @torek 1. are the repositories actually related? These repos are not related. As part of modularization, I just moved some folders to a new repo(repo-B). Meanwhile I'm developing in repo-B, I need the changes from other developers who pushed to repo-A.
2. **Are the repo-B files exact copies of the repo-A files, or do you need to find changes and apply them?**  Yes. 
3. **What are the relative pathnames?** Relative path names will be same.

Comment: OK, since they're not related, you can't use the commits directly, but since the files are literal copies, you can just have two working trees checked out: one for (a clone of) A, one for (a clone of) B. When there are new commits in A that affect files in B, check out each of those that you wish copied, copy the files to the working tree for B, commit in B using the appropriate commit message, repeat until done, and push or otherwise transfer the new commits to any other copies of B that need to be maintained.

Comment: (This should be pretty easy to script, once you've done it manually once or twice to get a feel for it.)

Comment: @torek Thanks, Just wanted to make sure whether this way preserve the commit history from repo-A

Comment: It doesn't. The commit history consists of the commits. You either have *the* commits (and hence the history), or you have some *other* commits (and hence some other history). The commits *are* the history, and vice versa. This is fundamental to Git. Two different histories might be called *equivalent* if they describe the same events, by the same people, but if they have different *hash IDs*, to Git they are *different histories*. Moreover, all it takes is any one single different commit in the past: then all future commits are different too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the perfect solution I wanted. git filter-repo can be used to rewrite the commit history just for the subfolders we wanted. Later we can pull these changes to the new repo.

Examples, are here: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES

Comment: Does it sync changes?